# Excel Chart not displaying X Axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I've got a chart in a spreadsheet in Excel 2010 which is using A chart = "Stacked Column in 3-D"

I have defined the Horizontal (Category) Axis Label in the Select Data Source window and it is correctly displaying my Axis labels inside the window.

When I click Ok - the chart does not display the Horizontal Axis as defined.

I click on the chart and select "Format Axis" but it only gives me access to the Y-Axis...

How do I show the X-Axis????

Answer (score 2):

While this may not be the answer you want, if you stick to 2D charts, you will find that:

[a] It is easier to format without such difficulties.

[b] It is easier for people to interpret the data in the graph.